# Retrieve Blackberry Browser session header properties

Tags: blackberry, browser, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde

I want to know what are the header properties used by Blackberry default browser session.
Since my http connection needs all the browser session header properties like Accept-Language,Accept-Encoding,Keep-Alive.

Comment: I didn't get. Do you need to add them or just verify/know what are the values?

Comment: @Eugen Martynov : Thank you for reply. Since my application portal address works correctly in browserfield and browser session displays xml response but not working in http connection,We need the browser headers properties to set for http connection.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to `HttpConnection` instance (it's not a `BrowserField`) you can set them yourself:

```
c.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.0");
```

Comment: Actually you can get access to HttpConnection for BrowserField also